# Add searchDisplayController.displaySearchBarInNavigationBar on Navigation bar with a search button

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I want to add a feature where we have a search button on navigation bar and on clicking that button , searchbar should come in the place of navigation bar .

Answer (score 0):

You can add the SearchBar as the subview of the NavigationBar when user clicks the SearchButton on the navigatioBar & brings the serachBar to front.

[navBar addSubview:searchBar];
[navBar bringSubviewToFront:searchBar];